# "extinct" or "turn extinct"?

Tags: poetry

I was reading a poetry. One of its line is:

```
"these voices need a pen before they turn extinct"
```

Now I wonder if it should be "turn extinct" or just "extinct"?

Comment: 1. Poetry doesn't always comply with strict rules of grammar. 2. Why do you think it should be *just "extinct"*? (It shouldn't, because it needs a verb there. Normally one says "become extinct".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Turn extinct" is unusual, and may have been chosen for poetry.

The more usual expression is "go extinct". "Turn" is sometimes used for "become, change state" (eg "turn red", "turn nasty" ="become aggressive or threatening") but would not normally be used with "extinct".

As for your last point, "extinct" is not a verb, so cannot be used on its own there: it needs a verb, normally either "go" or "become".

Comment: Perhaps with a little more license one might use 'extinguish' as the verbal form, or at any rate, one once might have.

Comment: @aabeba: You might use "be extinguished".

Comment: If you want to be drab... :P

Comment: @aabeba: the OED marks the intransitive sense of _extinguish_ as obsolete. But yes, it has occasionally been used that way.

Comment: I suppose the only way to bring it back from obsolescence would be to use it?

Comment: @aabeba: You might yourself extinguish before that usage be rescued from obsolescence.

Comment: @TRomano It is a fool's right to dream, is it not? Sooner may time snuff out me than be extinguished the dream.

Comment: @aabeba: Say what?  I need an exclamation point as a crutch at the end there.

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatically, and in modern English, one would probably say "become extinct".

However the line you quote has Iambic meter, in fact it's an Iambic hexameter (stresses in bold):

"these **voi**ces **need** a **pen** be**fore** they **turn** ex**tinct**"

The author is using [poetic license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license) (that link gives a similar example by Shakespeare to fit an iambic pentameter) to bend the rules of normal English for
effect and to make the line fit the meter. You'll find this a lot in poems.
One of the most common is to add a syllable to the past participle of a verb, long after this had ceased to be common usage.

In this example (from a translation of Tibullus' Elegies) the translator has to match the meter (rhythm) but also translate the words:

`Though I be agèd now, though head and chin
Now show them hoar y-hue'd with grizzling hair,`

The translator has stretched out the word "aged" to make two syllables "age-ed" to make it fit.

Comment: I would like to add that the poet is not professional